# UWP : How can I implement first time tutorial like Android in my uwp app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Android apps have a nice first time tutorial like Saavn. How can I show tutorials of my app to the user at first time of launch.How can I implement this Transparent view (which interacts with screen objects) in my UWP app?
I can think of just navigating to a page when the app first launches but I want to interact with the object in the UI as a method of teaching tutorials to my app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Photosharing app sample has something like that.